# LXQt Panel has dissapeared after installing Nvidia drivers

Tags: nvidia, d-bus, lxqt

(I've seen a few occurrences of a similar issue around so its possible I missed a viable solution in my searches)

I installed Nvidia drivers for my system following the instructions on the Arch Wiki (https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NVIDIA) using `nvidia-dkms` for `linux-zen` - adding the modules to `mkinitcpio.conf` and the `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` kernel parameter.

After restarting, most LXQt features seemed to have become disabled (Panel, Runner, Desktop and Alt-Tab overlay). Right clicking on the desktop still produced a generic menu with a list of software categories, some of which were installed but most not, and `lxqt-config` still works.

Rerunning `nvidia-xconfig` I managed to get the desktop up (i.e. the background and files in `~/Desktop` were showing), but I'm still unable to get any other LXQt features working.

Invoking `lxqt` binaries manually, I seem to get a bunch of DBus errors

```
# All three seem to do the same (show a search bar in a modal at the top of the screen), but `lxqt-runner` exits after the modal appears
> lxqt-session
> lxqt-runner
> startlxqt
Error name  "org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs"
Error msg   "No such interface “org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties”"
dbusCall: QDBusInterface is invalid "org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit" "/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager" "org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager"
```

The full logs here: https://pastebin.com/znxgwtfW

I am a tad lost as to how to fix this, so if anyone has had a similar thing or knows what's wrong I'd appreciate it

Here's my system:

```
Nvidia Card: RTX 2060 Super
Arch Linux
Kernel: `5.12.9-zen1-1-zen`
Nvidia-dkms: `nvidia-dkms-465.31-1`
Dkms: `dkms-2.8.4-1 `
LXQt: `lxqt-runner-0.17.0-1  lxqt-session-0.17.1-1 lxqt-panel-0.17.1-1`
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the driver installation had changed my screen layout and LXQt believed that the main monitor was a nonexistent one, putting the panel way offscreen. Solution was to just invoke `lxqt-config` and modify my monitor settings